# PHP Shopping Cart: How to update product quantity in cart using session variables?

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I am in the process of creating my first shopping cart project.But got stuck while updating the product quantity.

I want to update the product quantity using a session variable. Can anyone help me with the code and also tell me how to go about it?

Here is the my_cart.php page code

```
    <tr>
        <th class="tablerow">Product Code</th>
        <th class="tablerow">Product Name</th>
        <th class="tablerow">Image</th>
        <th class="tablerow">Quantity</th>
        <th class="tablerow">Price</th>
        <th class="tablerow">Total Price</th>
        <th class="tablerow">Action</th>                 
    </tr>

    <?php
    $grand_total = 0;                                   // For Calculating Grand Price
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id=>$quantity)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error Message");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {       
        $grand_total+= $row['product_price']*$quantity; // For Calculating Grand Price  
    ?>        

    <tr>                
        <td class="tablerow"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablerow"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablerow"><?php echo "<img height='50' width='50' src='admin/".$row['product_image']."'/>" ?></td>

        <form name="update_cart" action="update_cart.php" method="post">

        <td class="tablerow"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" /><br /><input type="image" src="admin/images/updatecart.png" name="Update" value="Update" /></td>

        </form>

        <td class="tablerow"><?php echo $row['product_price']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablerow"><?php echo $quantity*$row['product_price']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tablerow"><?php print "<a href='delete_cart.php?pid=".$row['id']."'><img src='admin/images/delete.png'></a>"; ?></td></form>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="tablerow" colspan="7">Grand Total: Rs <?php echo $grand_total; ?></td>
    </tr>       

    <tr>
        <td class="tablerow" colspan="7"><?php print "<a href='clear_cart.php'><img src='admin/images/clearcart.png'></a><a href='http://localhost/Shopping-Cart/front-end/'><img src='admin/images/continueshopping.png'></a><a href='update_cart.php'><img src='admin/images/placeorder.png'></a>";?></td>
    </tr>              

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the product quantity using a session variable

There is a question: from where you would like to update qnt on client or on server only (your session vars stores on server) ?
As I can suppose you would like your customer changes qnt in his browser (on client) and server should knows about ?
If so, you need on client use JS+Ajax request (Jquery easier way) that will send ajax request to file (eg: change_qnt.php)  and if success will update qnt on client (browser)

change_qnt.php will change session variable where you store your qnt and then return result if it will successful or not, depending it you update or not qnt on your visitor page.

Very simple example:

```
<script>
$('selector_that_will_change_qnt').click() {
.ajax ({
url: 'change_qnt.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'html',
success: function() { // code here if success request},
error: function(){ //code here if request was failed}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: On client end using a session variable. Here is the code for the add_cart.php page
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Buy']))
{
 $pid=$_POST['id'];  

$_SESSION['cart'][$pid]+=1;

header("location:my_cart.php?msg=Product Added Successfully");
}

Answer (score 0):

Save the all **product ids** in an session array. The index should be equal to the same as product id. It means if an user clicks or add a new product then save 1 at the position  `$_SESSION['cart']['product_id']` in your array. If user add the same product again then simply do `$_SESSION['cart']['product_id']++` and then you can print your array by using `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id=>$quantity)`. You can code the above concept easily.

Here is an example if you can understand anything from it.

```
if(isset(isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && !empty($_REQUEST['pid'])) {
    $_SESSION['item'] = $_SESSION['item'] + 1; //Total number of items in cart
    $p_id = $_REQUEST['pid']; //Clicked product's id
    $_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]++; //Increment in relevant index value by one
    $cost_query = "select * from product where id=$p_id";
    //Calculate cost here and store it in session variable to use in your main page or where you are displaying your cart
}
```

Comment: I have already done this in the add_cart.php page. Here is code 'session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Buy']))
{
 $pid=$_POST['id'];  

$_SESSION['cart'][$pid]+=1;

header("location:my_cart.php?msg=Product Added Successfully");
}'

But how to update the quantity? See, I have used a form. But I am not sure if this way I can update the quantity.

Comment: @user3252609 Do you know thw Ajax? If yes then after each click on "Buy product" update the '$_SESSION['cart'][$pid]' value by 1. Ajax will send the id of product to another page and if the id is set then update the array value by 1 for the relavent **product_id** index.